# SOQL: I need to display a Visualforce list of cases where each row can be expanded to display indirectly related cases

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, lookup

So there are 3 case records types: A, B, and C.

A and C cases both have lookups to B cases, but otherwise have no direct relationship.

I need to display a VF list of A cases where each row can be expanded to display all of the C cases that also point to the same B cases.

Here's a basic visual representation

A1 -> B1 <- C1, C2, C3 
A2 -> B2 <- C4, C5, C6 
A3 -> B3 <- C7, C8, C9

So, I should see a list of A cases, and each entry can be expanded to display "related" C cases.

I've played around with maps and inner selects, but I am utterly stumped.

Comment: Do you want help with the queries? or how to store the values so they can be accessed by the visualforce page?

Comment: edit: I misunderstood your question. I'm looking for help with both aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More step by step than navD87's approach:

```
public with sharing class MyController {

    public class CaseWrapper {
        public Case a {get; set;}
        public Case[] cs {get; set;}
        CaseWrapper(Case a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }

    public CaseWrapper[] getWrappers() {

        Set<Id> bIds = new Set<Id>();
        CaseWrapper[] wrappers = new CaseWrapper[] {};

        // Query the A Cases
        for (Case a: [
                select Name, CaseB__c
                from Case
                where RecordType.Name = 'A'
                and CaseB__c != null
                and ...
                order by Name
                ]) {
            wrappers.add(new CaseWrapper(a));
            bIds.add(a.CaseB__c);
        }

        // Query the B and C Cases
        Map<Id, Case> bs = new Map<Id, Case>([
                select Id, (
                        select Name
                        from CaseCRelationshipName__r
                        where RecordType.Name = 'C'
                        order by Name
                        )
                from Case
                where RecordType.Name = 'B'
                and Id in :bIds
                ]);

        // Add the C Cases to the wrapper
        for (CaseWrapper w : wrappers) {
            Case b = bs.get(w.a.CaseB__c);
            if (b != null) w.cs = b.CaseCRelationshipName__r;
            else ws.cs = new Case[] {};
        }

        return wrappers;
    }
}
```

with the Visualforce (without any expand collapse fancyness):

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper">
    <apex:column value="{!wrapper.a.Name}"/>
    <apex:column>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapper.cs}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Noticed a typo : bIds.add(c.CaseB__c) should be bIds.add(a.CaseB__c)

Comment: @navD87 Thanks I'll fix. Probably some others in there too...

Comment: // Query the B and C Cases
        Map<Id, Case> bs = new Map<Id, Case>( select .....

Error: Expecting right parentheses, found 'select'

Comment: @David I forgot the square brackets - added now.

Comment: @KeithC Thanks! I just got your class to save, and I'll be testing it out over the next few minutes. Thank you SO much for helping me so far, and I'll be checking in to confirm this solution after I test it out.

Comment: @KeithC Error: Unknown property 'wrappers' referenced in vf page. is this just a typo? I'm unfamiliar with wrappers

Comment: @David That the method name `getWrappers` with the `get` removed and is case insensitive. Did you reference the controller class in the apex:page tag?

Comment: @KeithC Oh, I didn't need help with that error (I mean to paste this one: Unknown property 'MobileCaseCollector.CaseWrapper.a'")

Comment: @David I'd left off the get and set; added now to the CaseWrapper class. Visualforce requires at lest the get.

Comment: @KeithC Thanks! I got it to save just now., but it isn't grabbing any of the C cases. When you when you query for B and C cases, does "CaseCRelationshipName__r" refer to the child relationship name ("Cases__r")?

Comment: @David Yes it's the name from the parent to the child that by convention is set to a plural. (The name from the child to the parent is by convention singular.) I wasn't sure if you have one (for both A and C) or two separate for A and C) of these fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can query out all A and C cases at once, assuming you need to display all As with related Cs on the Visualforce page.

```
List<Case> allCases = [SELECT Id, RecordType.Name, B_Case_lookup FROM Case WHERE RecordType.Name == 'A' OR RecordType.Name == 'C'];
List<Case> Acases = new List<Case>();
Map<Id, List<Case>> cCasesBybCaseIds = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();    

//Get all the B lookup Ids from the A records
for(Case case : allCases) {
    if(case.RecordType.Name == A) {
        aCases.add(case);
    } else if(case.RecordType.Name == C && case.B_Case_lookup != null) {
        if(cCasesBybCaseIds.containsKey(case.B_Case_lookup)) {
            cCasesBybCaseIds.get(case.B_Case_lookup).add(case);
        } else {
            cCasesBybCaseIds.put(case.B_Case_lookup, new List<Case>{case});
        }
    }
}
```

You can further relate As to Cs directly by creating a map that maps A Case Ids to a list of C cases.

```
Map<Id, List<Case>> cCasesByACaseIds = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();
for(Case case : Acases) {
    if(cCasesBybCaseIds.containsKey(case.B_Case_lookup)) {
        cCasesByACaseIds.put(case.Id, cCasesBybCaseIds.get(case.B_Case_lookup));
    }
}
```